# Anyone encounter these Logic symbols?

Tags: logic

[image: Logic matrix]

These diagrams are equivalent representations of the 2-ary boolean functions. What are the symbols used in the top left diagram?

(Source: [wikicommons user mate2code](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Logic_matrix;_operations.svg))

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the symbols in the upper left diagram are not standard in the field of symbolic logic.

Comment: I'm not even going to follow your link, but I predict it's an illustration created by user "Lipedia". He (or she) is somewhat infamous for creating extremely confusing and unclear (though sometimes visually beautiful) "visualizations" of a range of discrete math topics. There's a good chance he invented some of this symbolism himself and nobody else uses it.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Me too. But why have they been included in this compiled image? It's been driving me crazy.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The user is mate2code. Confusing visualizations are one thing, but I don't see how they would be even hypothetically useful in this case. If mate is a troll, he is a good one.

Comment: It looks like Lipedia's account is [now called Mate2code](http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=User:Lipedia&redirect=no). I don't think he's a troll; he's way too prolific and lavishes too much loving care on his illustrations for that. But he also has a real problem with understanding which kind of diagrams will be any use for a reader.

Comment: @Henning: You’re right; at least Lipedia redirects to mate2code. (And that’s a *really* impressive collection of graphics.) Oh, and it says that no pages link to this particular picture.

Comment: Found another image using these symbols, perhaps he is trying to institute them: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/16x16_matrix_like_octeract_Hasse_diagram.svg. It is well known that a logician is not successful until he has created his own notation and forced other people to use it.

Comment: It appears to be what he calls [Nibble Shorthands](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/User:Lipedia/hat#Nibble_shorthands), which represent nibbles, I guess. You could probably ask him how he came up with them and why their shapes make sense, I would bet he has a beautiful answer.

Comment: @AlfonsoFernandez Thanks! Just what I needed.

Comment: @AlfonsoFernandez: That's as close to an answer as we'll ever get, I think. (I tend to use the symbols `0123456789ABCDEF` to represent nibbles, but I'm just a freak, I suppose).

Comment: @Alfonso Your comment is probably as complete an answer as is likely to be given; could you promote it to an answer?

Comment: @Lord_Farin Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment by Henning Makholm and a short link trace I conducted, these are nonstandard symbols invented by Wikimedia user [mate2code](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User%3aMate2code) (formerly Lipedia).

mate2code calls them [nibble shorthands](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Hat#Nibble_shorthands), and they simply represent all possible nibbles (four digit binary strings, more commonly represented by the numbers $0$ to $15$ or by the hexadecimal digits `0` to `F`), in an order which can be seen [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/Tesseract_Hasse_diagram_with_nibble_shorthands.svg) (by interpreting the red dots under each symbol as $1$'s and the white dots as $0$'s).

**Note**: The links may be volatile, as they refer to Wikimedia user pages.